# SonarQube don't start

Tags: database, web, sonarqube, connectivity

I'm trying to install SonarQube on my CentOS7 server.

When i try to access via web I see this:

[web_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me9Cm.png)

It's supposed to show a SonarQube page right??

Here i put my logs and configs:

**web.log:**

```
2019.08.29 17:24:54 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2019.08.29 17:25:05 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2019.08.29 17:25:05 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019.08.29 17:25:06 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Kurt Wagner] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2019.08.29 17:25:06 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2019.08.29 17:25:06 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.4.0.25310 / ad64a17b531c0e1f6fef0ce7e4d0d0b060977754
2019.08.29 17:25:06 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
2019.08.29 17:25:06 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:108)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:88)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:231)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:190)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:86)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "sonar")
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:106)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "sonar"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:451)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

**sonar.log:**

```
2019.08.29 17:28:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2019.08.29 17:28:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2019.08.29 17:28:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.08.29 17:28:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.08.29 17:28:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process6725369398987844378properties
2019.08.29 17:28:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2019.08.29 17:28:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process3428525909039640490properties
```

**systemctl status httpd:**

```
[oksmart@CLOUDSVRSONAR01 logs]$ systemctl status httpd -l
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-29 16:59:00 CEST; 33min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 5697 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5834 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 50; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─5834 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5835 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5836 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5837 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5839 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5900 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5901 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5903 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5904 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5905 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─5906 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Aug 29 16:59:00 CLOUDSVRSONAR01 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 29 16:59:00 CLOUDSVRSONAR01 httpd[5834]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::250:56ff:fe01:114a. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Aug 29 16:59:00 CLOUDSVRSONAR01 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/sonar.oksmart.es.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
#   ProxyPreserveHost On
#   ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
#   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
    TransferLog /var/log/httpd/sonar.oksmart.es_access.log
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/sonar.oksmart.es_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

NOTE: I commented the proxy options because if i comment out those lines, i get an error on the web page.

**sonar.sh :**

```
DEF_APP_NAME="SonarQube"
DEF_APP_LONG_NAME="SonarQube"
APP_NAME="${DEF_APP_NAME}"
APP_LONG_NAME="${DEF_APP_LONG_NAME}"
WRAPPER_CMD="./wrapper"
WRAPPER_CONF="../../conf/wrapper.conf"
PRIORITY=
PIDDIR="."
RUN_AS_USER=root
...
```

**sonar.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube service
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop
User=root
Group=sonar
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any idea of what am i doing wrong??

Firewall is disabled.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the web container failed to startup because of database authentication.

Besides that, you commented out your proxy config, that's why you're seeing default Apache homepage.

Comment: Hello Andrik and thanks,

I've tried to uncomment the proxy options in the .conf and i get the error i said:

"Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server"

Besides of that, I see errors in my web.log that say that:
"FATAL: password authentication failed for user "sonar""

Any idea?? The user and pasword should be ok as you see in my first comment.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you setup the database credentials on $SONARQUBE-HOME/conf/sonar.properties? I'm asking because you didn't mention it on your question.

The proxy error mentioned occur because Apache is not recieving a valid HTTP response from Tomcat. Did you try access SonarQube directly accesing localhost:9000?

Comment: Finally solved. I just started a fresh new installation. Not sure enough what was the problem :(

Thanks for the help!